Wald-Wolfowitz runs test on white noise
I am looking for ways to inspect whether a time series is different from white noise (WN), where white noise is understood as a process with a zero mean, constant variance and zero autocorrelation at all the nonzero lags. I could  inspect directly whether the mean is zero, the variance is constant and the autocorrelations at all nonzero lags are zero, and I do that. But besides these points, would it make sense to apply the Wald-Wolfowitz (WW) runs test? I ran into it accidentally (implemented in randtests::runs.test in R) and am not sure what to make of it in this context.
I edited the question twice for clarity, so there is a slight mismatch between it and Ben's answer. This is my fault, not Ben's. 

Here are some other recent (and not so recent) questions of mine that have not been answered. Would you care taking a look? Your help will be appreciated.

Different in what way?  When we test for departure from some assumed distribution, we usually need to specify some broad alternative that we want to test for, so what is it here?  A test against IID values following an alternative distribution?  A test of autocorrelation?  A test of a hidden periodic signal in the time-series?  Etc.?

@Ben, I am trying to understand whether the WW test can be useful for detecting deviations from WN. I am not prespecifying which deviations I am interested in, as this is not my starting point. I am asking if it will ever make sense to apply the WW test for inspecting whether a process is WN, or whether we should never do this because there is no situation (no type of deviation) for which the WW test would work given the null hypothesis of a process being WN.

It gives similar results to lag1 autocorrelation tests, with possible differences introduced by discretization of the series from numeric to binary. If  you are testing for normal white noise, you are better off using an exact test that assumes normality instead of this one.
This said, every test is good for some alternative hypothesis and worse for others. Which test is best, depends on your alternative hypothesis.
Edit
I'm writing this part after in the comments the case has been raised about the robustness of test for relaxed WN assumptions. WW run test was designed for testing independent Bernoulli sequences, and it also work with IID numeric time series, by applying a threshold (usually the median) to the series, which effectively makes it an independent Bernoulli sequence.
White noise is often assumed to be IID, but wide sense WN just requires second order stationarity and uncorrelation. Under these circumstances, a process has flat spectral function and is therefore a WN. Second order stationarity allows distributions that are not identical to each other, but only for the first two moments: a process $X_t$ could be skewed to the left for some $t$ and to the right for some others, and still be WN. The problem with this is that, when you discretize the process, the first two moments blow up.
Let's make an example:
$$
X_t \overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} 
\begin{cases}
    -1 & P = 0.8 \\
    4  & P = 0.2
\end{cases} \\
Y_t = 
\begin{cases} 
X_t  & t \text{ even} \\
-X_t & t \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$
Both processes have 0 mean and constant variance, and both are uncorrelated at any lag. They are not quite symmetric and if I turn $X_t$ into a Bernoulli sequence for instance, the mean will move from 0. That is not a problem because WW runs test can handle uneven samples, and $X_t$ is IID, so the transformation yields another IID process.
If I turn $Y_t$ into a Bernoulli sequence, however, the mean stays 0, but the second order moments get screwed, and lag1 autocorrelation is markedly negative. This is possible because the distribution of $Y_t$ is not identical at all time steps. WW run test would fail for $Y_t$ because IID is effectively the hypothesis being tested.

Does a process being WN implies it passes the WW runs test? Not a particular path of WN but the data generating process (DGP).

IID white noise passes the WW runs test. non-ID weakly stationary white noise could fail the test if the samples have different distributions while having same mean and variance.

Interesting. Could you construct an example where it fails (not just for a single path but for the data generating process) and explain the logic behind the construction?

If a process is "white noise" this means that its values are exchangeable which means that the null hypothesis for the Wald-Wolfowitz runs test is true.  The Wald-Wolfowitz runs test is generally useful against alternative hypotheses where there is non-exchangeability that manifests in more or less runs than would be expected for an exchangeable time-series.  This includes cases where there is autocorrelation in the time-series, which can manifest either in longer runs (for positive autocorrelation) or shorter runs (for negative autocorrelation).
The Wald-Wolfowitz runs test is a consistent hypothesis test, so for any fixed significance level $0<\alpha<1$, as the amount of data goes to infinity you get:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\text{Reject }H_0|H_0) &= \alpha, \\[6pt]
\mathbb{P}(\text{Reject }H_0|H_\text{A}) &\rightarrow 1. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
By construction, the test will reject the null hypothesis with probability $\alpha$ if it is true so there is no "must pass" property even with an infinite amount of data.  Nevertheless, with an infinite amount of data the test will always reject the null hypothesis if it is false.
This test is just one possible test you can use to see if there is a departure from "white noise".  Whether it is sufficient/optimal really depends on the type of departures from white noise that you want to test for.  Other possible tests that may be fruitful are direct tests of autocorrelation (e.g., Durbin-Watson test, Breusch-Godfrey test, Ljung-Box test), direct tests for periodic signals (e.g., permutation-spectrum test).

Thank you. Would you have any comment on the correctness of carlo's answer?

I take "white noise" to mean IID (so that it is exchangeable).  If you take weaker definitions than this (e.g., only second order stationarity) then it might be possible to construct pathological examples where the distribution is non-exchangeable (e.g., through relationships in higher order moments) so that the null hypothesis of the WW test is false.  In any case, WW test can be used to detect any departure from exchangeability that manifests in more or less runs than are expected under exchangeability.

Thank you, that clarifies it. I meant the weak sense white noise that only makes the first and second moments constant, and I overlooked the fact that white noise can be defined in a different way.
